# NodeJs - Creating json file with Dynamic data

Tags: node.js, json

I am reading excel file & adding excel data into json array, using below code:

```
await workbook.xlsx.readFile(`${__dirname}/myTestData.xlsx`).then(() => {
    workbook.worksheets.forEach(async (sheet, x) => {
      let dataJsArr = [];
      let dataJs = [];
      let sh = workbook.getWorksheet(sheet.id);

      for (let i = 2; i <= sh.rowCount; i++) {
        sh.getRow(1).eachCell((cell) => {
         dataJs[cell.value] = sh.getRow(i).getCell(cell.col).text;
       });
      }

      dataJsArr.push({ ...dataJs });

      let outPutFile =`${__dirname}/myFiles/Data//myTestData.json`;

      fs.writeFileSync(
          outPutFile,
          JSON.stringify({ dataJsArr }),
          { spaces: 2 }
        );
   });
});
```

Note: Sometimes I am getting multiple sheets in excel because of that added extra loop for worksheets. So in that case multiple json file will create.

When I am executing code Json files properly generated. Json file data:

```
{
    "dataJsArr": [
    {
        "customerId": "1",
        "customerName": "John",
        "customerAddress": "CA"
    },
    {
        "customerId": "2",
        "customerName": "Kely",
        "customerAddress": "NW"
    },
    {
        "customerId": "3",
        "customerName": "Mike",
        "customerAddress": "WS"
    }
    ]
}
```

I want json data without "dataJsArr" like

```
[
    {
        "customerId": "1",
        "customerName": "John",
        "customerAddress": "CA"
    },
    {
        "customerId": "2",
        "customerName": "Kely",
        "customerAddress": "NW"
    },
    {
        "customerId": "3",
        "customerName": "Mike",
        "customerAddress": "WS"
    }
]
```

Got solution on this:

Just removed brackets inside Json stringify & it worked for me

```
JSON.stringify(dataJsArr);
```